# When Automatically Refreshing a DIV, is it possible to not reload an Iframe within the DIV?

Tags: php, jquery, video, refresh

I'm currently refreshing a div on a page every 5 seconds using the following JS

```
 if (auto_refresh === false) { 
   auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){$('#bottom_middle').load(thisurl + '&timer=' + new Date().getTime() + ' #bottom_middle' );}, 5000); 
 } else {
   clearInterval(auto_refresh); auto_refresh = false;
 }
```

Inside this div, users can embedd video from Youtube using an Iframe.

Is it possible, when refreshing the DIV to not reload the Iframe everytime?

Answer (score 3):

No. if you're refreshing the entirety of the div, then the iframe itself will be refreshed as well. You can't prune/graft a DOM tree and say "replace this element, except for this one child of the one we're replacing".

You'll have to split up your update into multiple parts, and update only the parts of the div that AREN'T the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Add a separate container that wraps the part of div that isn't the iframe and load into that. If you can't change the markup from server you can always use jQuery wrap() method to wrap the elements you want reloaded and then use your load() method on the new container

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/